# Conseguir delimitar a alinhar minha caixa de texto

Tags: html, html5

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e91Qv.png)Boa Tarde, sou designer e estou me aventurando na programação de front recentemente. Estou com um problema para conseguir alinhar um texto dentro de um background, o código está abaixo:

```
<td width="700" height="224" colspan="6" bgcolor="#5dba6a" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"> 
        <img src="images/dissidio2.png" width="235" height="182" align="right" border="0" alt="">
        <font style="font-family:Arial,Open Sans,Verdana;font-size:18px;text-align:left;color:#ffffff">
            Para este início de ano<br> 
            temos <strong>CONDIÇÕES ESPECIAIS</strong><br>
            pra você que vai reajustar o valor<br> 
            do contrato devido ao <strong>DISSÍDIO</strong>.</font>
```

Gostaria de deixar assim[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIGKN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você está fazendo uma peça de emailmarketing, se for isso tem algumas limitações mesmo.
Para posicionar o texto você precisa usar padding ou margin.
Para isso funcionar você precisa colocar na tag  dentro do style, um display:block e depois inserir o padding ou margin.

Como a tag font é uma tag por padrão **inline (linha)**, ela não aceita padding e nem margin. semelhante a tag , , **, são tag de linha. Elas ocupam somente o espaço do tamanho delas, diferente de tag de block(bloco)** que ocupam todo o espaço onde ela está, fazendo com que o conteúdo seguinte dele vá parar na linha de baixo.

Solução:

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td width="700" height="224" colspan="6" bgcolor="#5dba6a" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"> 
                <img src="images/dissidio2.png" width="235" height="182" align="right" border="0" alt="">
                <font style="font-family:Arial,Open Sans,Verdana;font-size:18px;text-align:left;color:#ffffff; display: block;padding-top: 37px;">
                    Para este início de ano<br> 
                    temos <strong>CONDIÇÕES ESPECIAIS</strong><br>
                    pra você que vai reajustar o valor<br> 
                    do contrato devido ao <strong>DISSÍDIO</strong>.</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Se essa resposta te ajudo marque como útil.